# "a lead to target"

Tags: phrase-meaning

What does putting "a lead to target" mean? It's from [this](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-us-canada-63125238) BBC article

> Mr Giroir walked into the Oval Office wearing a dress uniform - as is customary for public health officers in the corps - and said to Mr Trump that facilities producing illegal drugs in Mexico should be handled by putting **"a lead to target"** to stop illicit substances from coming over the border.

Comment: It looks like there's [a closed question on English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/596358/whats-the-meaning-of-lead-to-target-in-this-context) that has an answer for this.